# proving a function to be holomorphic , its imaginary part bounded and real part unbounded

Tags: complex-analysis

This question is part of assignments which I am trying .

> Question: (a)  Let $f(z)=\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{1}{t-z}\ dt$, $z\in \mathbb{C}\setminus[-1,1]$. Prove that $f$ is holomorphic, its imaginary part is bounded, but real part is not.

(b) prove that $\lim_{z\to \infty} z f(z)$ exists and find it.

(c) also find a bounded non-constant holomorphic function on $\mathbb{C}\setminus[-1,1]$.

I have done (a) and $f$ comes out to be $\log(z^2 -1) $, $c$ is constant. But I am not able to prove that the limit exists ie part (b). I am confused that if I write $z =x+iy$ what does $z\to \infty$ would imply about $x$ and $y$?

For $c$ is $f(z) =1/1-z$ fine?

Kindly guide !!

Comment: How come there is a constant in your function? The integral is definite, so any constants of intefration should cancel.

Comment: Answer for c): Your function is not bounded since $f(1+\frac  1 n)=-n$.

Let $g(z)=e^{if(z)}$ where $f$ is the function defined in part a). Then $g$ is a bounded holomorphic non-constant function.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos Thanks!!

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks for (c) . can you also help with (b)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer for b): $\lim_{z \to \infty} \int_{-1}^{1} \frac z {t-z} dt=\lim_{z \to \infty} \int_{-1}^{1} (-1)dt=-2$ if we take take limit inside the integral. However this requires justification. So consider $$| \int_{-1}^{1} \frac z {t-z} dt+2|$$ $$\leq \int_{-1}^{1} | \frac z {t-z}+1| dt$$ $$ =\int_{-1}^{1} | \frac t {t-z}| dt $$ $$ \leq \int_{-1}^{1}  \frac {|t|} {|z|-2}| dt$$ $$ \leq \frac1 {|z|-2} \to 0$$.

[c) has been answered in a comment above].

Comment: After " So, consider " How does |$\int_{-1}^{1}\frac {z} {t-z}dt +2$|$\leq \int_{-1}^{1}|\frac{z}{t-z}+1| dt$ ? Can you please give an explanation?

Comment: $ \int_{-1}^{1} \frac z {t-z} dt+2=\int_{-1}^{1} [\frac z {t-z}+1] dt$ since $\int_{-1}^{1} 1 dt =2$. @User